# import modules into index view

Tags: angular, angular-material2

I'm doing my first angular2 project, so this might be a beginner question.

First, I've set up an angular2 project using angular cli.
After I added the [angular material](https://material.angular.io/) package to my project by adding it to the `src/app/app.module.ts` following the [instructions](https://material.angular.io/guide/getting-started):

```
import { MaterialModule } from '@angular/material';
// other imports 
@NgModule({
  imports: [MaterialModule],
  ...
})
export class AppModule { }
```

I was then able to use the components in my views, except in `index.html`, there it wouldn't work! I assume it's because the angular lifecycle anticipates that `index.html` is called before the dependencies are loaded from the `app.module.ts`.

I also tried loading the module into `main.ts` (in hope, that it would be loaded before before the `index.html` view):

`import { MaterialModule } from '@angular/material';`

Unfortunately this didn't fix the issue. How can I access the material components from the  `index.html` view?

Comment: why you want to use it on index.html, why not put your view in the root app template?

Comment: @XinMeng my approach was to put the page layout (navigation, content-area and footer) into the index.html, which is why I was trying to use the material styles. is this the wrong approach?

Comment: you need to put these things in one component such as root app. Maybe you can see the source code of CoreUI layout component https://github.com/mrholek/CoreUI-Free-Bootstrap-Admin-Template/blob/master/Angular2_CLI_Starter/src/app/layouts/full-layout.component.html

Comment: @XinMeng what do u mean with "root app"? I took a look at the source code of the component u sent me. Wrapping the page layout into a component seems like an interesting idea, but where should I insert this component?

Comment: if you use ng-cli, the root-app component will be created automatically.https://github.com/mrholek/CoreUI-Free-Bootstrap-Admin-Template/blob/master/Angular2_CLI_Starter/src/app/app.component.ts this coreUI use router, so he only put <router-outlet></router-outlet> in the template of this component. So you can put the view in this component

Comment: you can import the respective module and use the markup in the `index.html` however for properties and events you need to go for a component. So you should do this in the app component.